# LeetCode 127. Word Ladder wrong answer

Tags: python, algorithm

I am trying to solve this question on LeetCode
https://leetcode.com/problems/word-ladder/

My solution is as such

- isDiff checks whether each word differs by a character of 1

  I then generate a graph using an adjacency list connecting words differing by 1 char.

  If beginWord is not in the wordlist, I will add it in.

  dfs(w) finds the shortest path to endWord from w

  I then run dfs on the graph starting with beginWord to find the shortest path to endWord.

I also have a cache.
I passed 33/50 test cases and I got a wrong answer for test case 34, but I don't see any
flaw in the logic behind my code.
I understand that my generation of adjacency list and using dfs instead of bfs isn't very efficient, but I still don't understand why the code wouldn't work.

```
class Solution:
    def ladderLength(self, beginWord: str, endWord: str, wordList: List[str]) -> int:
        if endWord not in wordList:
            return 0

        def isDiff1(w1,w2):
            counter = 0
            for i in range(len(w1)):
                if w1[i] != w2[i]:
                    counter += 1
            return True if counter <= 1 else False
        if beginWord not in wordList:
            wordList.append(beginWord)
        # O(n)
        adjList = { word:[] for word in wordList }
        # O(n^2*len(w))
        for w1 in adjList:
            for w2 in wordList:
                if w1 == w2:
                    continue
                if isDiff1(w1,w2):
                    adjList[w1].append(w2)
        
        # dfs returns the minimum num of steps to reach endWord from w
        # if it cannot reach endWord, it returns 0
        vis = set()
        cache = {}
        def dfs(w):
            if w == endWord:
                return 1
            if w in vis:
                return 0
            if w in cache:
                return cache[w]
            
            canReach = False
            minSteps = float('inf')
            vis.add(w)
            for neighbor in adjList[w]:
                temp = dfs(neighbor)
                if temp:
                    canReach = True
                    minSteps = min(minSteps,temp)
            vis.remove(w)
            cache[w] = minSteps+1 if canReach else 0
            return cache[w]
        
        return dfs(beginWord)
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the cache. Your algorithm assumes that it doesn't matter which nodes had already been visited before getting to node A to determine what the shortest path is from A to B. But it does matter, because the set of visited nodes is a constraint for which paths are still available to get to node B. And so you might end up storing a length in the cache for node A that would not be optimal in other cases.

Comment: Ohh okay that makes so much sense, I see the issue now, thanks alot for the help!

Comment: If you wish you can mark the answer as accepted. No obligation.